# Get file size after downloading URL content with wget

Tags: bash, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to write a bash script that will download the contents of a URL (not recursive) and then analyze the file that was downloaded.

If the downloaded file is a text file (i.e index.html) I want to know the size of the file and count the number of characters within that file.

If the file is an image file I just want to know the file size.

Right now I'm working with `wget` and downloading the contents of the input URL, but the problem is that when I do this inside my script I don't know the file name of the file that was downloaded.

#### So, the two main question are:

1. How can I get the filename in my script after using `wget` to perform some analyzing operations on the file?
2. How can I deterime the file type of the downloaded file?

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: The default filename is the last component of the URL that was fetched, IIRC.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my post I've been working with wget but as i also mentioned I can't access the filename from inside the script. When just working in the terminal it's not a problem, since I can run wc -c etc on the file, but can't manage to do it within the script.

Comment: Why can't you run `wc -c` on the file in your script? Show us what you've tried, and explain what sort of errors you're seeing or where the scripts is behaving in ways other than what you expected.

Comment: Like i said, I can't run wc -c in my script since I don't know the file name on which to run the command on. That's the whole essence of my question, how can I retrieve the file name from inside the script after running the wget command.

Comment: Do you have to retain the file name given by the web server, or can you force it into a file name of your choosing?  For example, can you download the URL to `myfile` for every script run, or something like that?

Comment: I mean that would kind of work but the thing is I want the script to be repeatable, so if I set a name to the file run the script several times on different URLs there will be a clash with the file names. So, the best thing would be to use the wget filename when it saves the file locally so I can run the wc commands on that filename.

Comment: @azemi: The problem is that wget doesn't make the file name easily available to the caller.  While it's likely possible to parse the output, it will be cumbersome and error prone.

Would adding a timestamp to make the file name unique work?  For example, `wget-2021-02-04-1614` for a filename?

Keep in mind that we don't have the "big picture" on what you're trying to do here.  We don't know *why* you're trying to do this.

Comment: @BenScott Yea a time stamp might be more appropriate. Well the "big picture" I guess I just to analyze files from a given web page, weather it be the index.html file, or some images to get an idea of the complicity of a webpage. But I'm reluctant to say that this is a school assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did finally manage to solve it.

```
#!usr/bin/env bash
URL="$1"
FILENAME=$(date +%y-%m-%d-%T) #Set the current date and time as the filename
wget -O "$FILENAME" "$URL"    #Download the content from the URL and set the filename
FILE_INFO=$(file "$FILENAME") #Store the output from the 'file' command

if [[ "$FILE_INFO" == *"text"* ]]
then 
 echo "It's a text file"
elif [[ "$FILE_INFO" == *"image"* ]]
then 
 echo "It's an image"
fi
```

Special thanks to Ben Scott for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest setting the file name `wget` will write to, using the `-O` switch.  One can then generate a file name, tell `wget` to download the URL to that file name, and run whatever analysis tools one wants, using the file name you picked.

The idea here is, you not have to figure out what name the web site or URL or `wget` will pick -- you are controlling the parameters.  That is a useful programming technique in general.  The less the user or some external program or website can provide for input, the more robust and simpler your program code will be.

As for picking a file name, you could use a timestamp.  The `date` utility can generate a timestamp for you, if you give it a `+FORMAT` parameter.  Alternatively, since you mention this is part of an analysis tool, maybe you don't want to save the file at all.  In that case, try a tool like `mktemp` to generate a guaranteed unique file name, and then remove it before exiting.

For more information, see the manual pages `wget(1)`, `date(1)`, and `mktemp(1)`.

Not giving complete working code, in case anyone ever gets this as school assignment, and they stumble across this question.  I wouldn't want to make it too easy for that hypothetical person.  ;-)  Of course, if someone asked more specific questions, I'd likely clarify my answer for them.

Comment: Thank you very much Ben. Regarding my second question, how can I determine the file type of the downloaded file? Usually I just use the `file` command, but that prints out a quite long output and can be hard to use inside the script. Do you have any suggestions on how I can determine the filetype inside the script?